# Posting programatically on facebook using facebook sdk for android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I tried to post on my wall a message by clicking on a button in my activity. I first logged in and i am able to get some of my personal information from facebook too. But, when i am trying to post something on wall. It is not working.

```
public void postOnWall(String msg) {
        Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
         try {
                String response = mFacebook.request("me");
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", "Test Message");
                parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
                response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                        "POST");
                Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
                if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                        response.equals("false")) {
                   Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
                }
         } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

This is the function i am trying to post on to my wall.

Can anybody help me out.

Response from facebook:

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user","type":"OAuthException","Code":2500}}
```

Code to login:

```
public void loginToFacebook() {
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the response from Facebook?

Comment: I have added it to my post.. check

Comment: Just to make sure, did you ask for post permissions when the user logged in?

Comment: what permissions?? i dont know about them

Comment: can you post the code you use to let the user log in to Facebook?

Comment: i have added the code in the post, check

Comment: publish_stream is deprecated since years. where do you guys copy your code from? why don´t you just take a look at the facebook docs?

Comment: Its working correct for login ..  can you provide me the code for posting